# Can you still install Ubuntu 10.10 with Wubi?

Tags: wubi

I am trying to help a friend get set up with Ubuntu and want to recommend Wubi for his install (he is not very computer savvy). I had recently tried the Wubi download from Ubuntu.com and the only option it gave me was to install Natty.

Is there any way I can get Wubi to install 10.10 Maverick? Preferably just the EXE file, not having to download an entire disc image as the friend has no idea how to burn discs.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wubi.exe from http://releases.ubuntu.com/maverick/ or you can download the desktop CD ISO as mentioned already. Or refer to the Wubi Guide's [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_install_Ubuntu.3F)  for more options.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice it down there... But does it really download 10.10, not the latest (Natty) or the LTS (Lucid)?

Comment: Yes. Wubi.exe's are different for each release and can only download that specific release.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [download the maverick disk](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/) and mount it using something like [Daemon Tools Lite](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads). Disks have wubi on them.

No burning involved.

Step by step:

1. Find out what architecture is supported.
2. [Download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/) the appropriate disk.
3. [Download](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) and install Daemon Tools Lite.
4. Mount the disk like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTapZIx9DnQ).
5. Open wubi from the disk.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will ship my friend a maverick disc. I was hoping to find a wubi.exe that would give me the option of which Ubuntu to install.